# Working with several line of Detail in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got this problem
I have this Table

```
Case     Order          Amount
1         1               50
1         2               20
1         3               25 
2         1               35
2         2               40
2         3               38
3         1               45
3         2               50
3         3               25
```

So what I want is Case 1 Order 1 will subtract  the amount from Case 2 order 1, and then will subtract Case 3  Order 1  from Case 2 Order 1, then Case 1 order  2  subtract Case 2 Order 2 , then subtract Case 3 order 2  and so on 
is like a chain reaction

Formula(Case 1 Order 1-Case 2 Order 1)-Case 3 order 1

And the result have to be like this

```
Case     Order          Amount
1         1               50
1         2               20
1         3               25 
2         1               Result (35-50)=-15
.         .
3         1               Result (-15-45)
```

Comment: According to your explanation, the result of Case 2 Order 1 should be `50 - 35`, not `35 - 50`. Can you clarify? Also: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry Thanks

Comment: I have a Sql table , I got into the First Value , but when i have more than 2 its wrong, query :Select A3.Case,A2.Order(Case when A2.Seq=A3.Seq and A2.Case<A3Case then (A3.Amount-A2.Amount) else A3.Amount)  as Amount
from A2
inner join A2 as A3
on A2.Invoice=A3.Invoce and A2.Order=A3.Order)

Comment: So the formula is: take the first amount and then subtract all following? 50 -> 50 - 35 -> 50 - 35 - 45 ...?

Comment: Is a Invoice stuff, Case 1 is the original Invoice, and stay intact , case 2 is when you made modification to the invoice, so you subtract the amount to the first amount , then case 3 is more modification to the invoice so you subtract this to Case 2, but  Always have to match the Order for example Case 1 Order 1 -Case 2 Order 1-Case 3 Order 1, so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thorsten's solution probably uses the correct logic, it's just using a wrong column name in the SUM:

```
select 
  mycase, 
  myorder, 
  (
    select sum(case when mycase = 1 then amount else -amount end)
    from mytable other
    where other.myorder = mytable.myorder
    and other.mycase <= mytable.mycase
  ) as amount
from mytable
order by mycase, myorder;
```

What's your SQL Server release? 
If it supports Cumulative Sums it's a simple:

```
select t.*,
   sum(case when mycase = 1 then Amount else -Amount end) 
   over (partition by myorder 
         order by mycase
         rows unbounded preceding)
from tab as t
```

Comment: Thanks dnoeth, , my version SQL2008R2, let me see is this work, but you only include 1 Case, its have to be for the 3 cases

Comment: Thanks dnoeth, , my version SQL2008R2, let me see is this work, but you only include 1 Case, its have to be for the 3 cases, this is a invoice line, so if you modify one of the line of the invoice, have to subtract the previous line with   the Same order Number , So the invoice can be modify N times , First they show the original lines of the invoice, then they subtract the new amount to the previous one is the line Number is the same

Comment: @Luis64: AFAIK Cumulative Sums are only supported in SS2012. Btw, this answer does exactly what you describe, subtract all following *amounts* from the 1st amount :)

Comment: Let me Explain better , for Example you have the invoice #1 the invoice have 3 lines of details with the amount, some times you can modify the invoice with more products or few product, so when you modify they add new lines of details  ad add 01 to the invoice so I have to subtract the lines from original invoice every time somebody modify it, but the line number have to be equal to the line number and the first line keep the same

Comment: @Luis64: Please check if your example returns correct data, it uses *35-50-45* but in your comment to Heinz you say it's *50-35-45* and this is what both queries return.

Comment: I want the Results 50-35=15, then If they have another line of detail 15-45, and then with the line 2 the same, but example only see the first line , but can be multiples lines

Answer (score 0):

You need a correlated subquery where you add up the amounts. The formula is rather easy as you can see:

```
select 
  mycase, 
  myorder, 
  (
    select sum(case when mycase = 1 then amount else -amount end)
    from mytable other
    where other.myorder = mytable.myorder
    and other.mycase <= mytable.mycase
  ) as amount
from mytable
order by mycase, myorder;
```

I named the columns `mycase` and `myorder`, because `case` and `order` are both reserved words in SQL. Of course you could use these names with quotes (`"order"`, `"case"`) instead, but I don't like to have to quote column names.

Comment: That can also be done with SUM OVER, so you don't need a subquery at all, but I don't have time to write it now. Sorry. Maybe later today...

Comment: As dnoeth has pointed out, I simply confused the column name. Seems I was too much in a hurry. I am glad dnoeth could help you there and even show you the SUM OVER query I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, I figure out using this formula that I found over here:

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ORDER BY (num1) AS rn
        FROM    mytable
        )
SELECT  qc.*, qc.num1 - qp.num2
FROM    q qc
LEFT JOIN
        q qp
ON      qp.rn = qc.rn - 1
```